# How to conditionally disable the LWC Standard Datatable buttons

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have two buttons called **Add** and **Remove**  in my datatable columns, i have  a checkbox field called **isActive** on my **Account** object.
If **isActive=true**, on load of my component **Add** button should disable and **Remove** button should enable, if **isActive=false**, my **Add** button should enable and **Remove** button should disable.

How to achieve this using Standard Datatable in LWC

Here is the sample code.

```
const columns = [ 
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type:'text', initialWidth:180},
    { label: 'Account Number', fieldName: 'AccountNumber', type: 'text',wrapText: true, initialWidth:475},
    {type: 'button', initialWidth:140, typeAttributes: {
        label: 'Add',  
        name: 'add',  
        title: 'Add',
        value: 'Add',  
        iconPosition: 'right',
        variant: 'brand',
        alternativeText: 'Add',
        disabled:{fieldName: 'isActive'},
        
    }},
    {type: 'button', initialWidth:155, typeAttributes: {
        label: 'Remove', 
        name: 'Remove',  
        title: 'Remove',    
        value: 'Remove',  
        iconPosition: 'left',
        variant: 'destructive',
        alternativeText: 'Remove',
        disabled:{fieldName: 'isActive'},//How to use NOT (!) operator here using same checkbox field??
    }},
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to patch in a field "isNotActive" in your data so you can use the opposing value. There's no way to do otherwise with buttons.

If you use the action column instead, you can conditionally determine what to display. This is actually in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation):

```
// Other column data here
{ type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: this.getRowActions } },
```

...

```
getRowActions(row, doneCallback) {
    const actions = [];
        if (row['isActive']) {
            actions.push({
                'label': 'Deactivate',
                'iconName': 'utility:block_visitor',
                'name': 'deactivate'
            });
        } else {
            actions.push({
                'label': 'Activate',
                'iconName': 'utility:adduser',
                'name': 'activate'
            });
        }
        // simulate a trip to the server
        setTimeout(() => {
            doneCallback(actions);
        }), 200);
}
```

You can do the callback immediately instead of simulating a callout, or simply return the value to show. This is the preferred way of doing this in Lightning.

Answer (score 3):

there is a way more simple, just put a field data as the toggle:

```
typeAttributes:
{
    iconName: 'utility:upload',
    name: 'upload',
    disabled : {fieldName :'uploaded'},
    iconClass: 'slds-icon-text-success'
}
```